# Dropdown dont show onClick React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dropdown

Hello so i have a question when i click on my navbar icon it shoul open a dropdown so when i click it changes the div name but the css props stays the initial div class anyone can help me, i dont know where im doing mistake i think it should have worked

```
  <div className='action'>
        <div className='profile' onClick={this.menuToggle}>
          <img src={Avatar} alt="Avatar" />
        </div>

        <div className={`menuDropdown ${active ? "active" : ""}`}>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#' />Ver Perfil</li>
            <li><a href='#' />Logout</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
    class NavBarClient extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      active: false

    };

  }



  menuToggle = () => {

    this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });

  }

  render() {
    const { active } = this.state;
```

```
.menuDropdown{
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    right: -10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    box-sizing: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    .active{
        top:80px;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why is `.active` inside `.menuDropdown`?

Comment: is to change the class name and get the .active css properties

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the css file you should get the `.active` css object out of the `.menuDropdown` object.

```
.menuDropdown{
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    right: -10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    box-sizing: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

    .active{
        top:80px;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```